Next auth(Authjs) session is null on Nextjs 14 server page
import { auth } from "@/auth";


const page = async ({children}) => {
  const session = await auth();

  return <div>{children}</>
};

// My auth config

import { Pool } from "@neondatabase/serverless";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import PostgresAdapter from "@auth/pg-adapter";

import { authConfig } from "./auth.config";

export const { handlers, auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth(() => {
  const pool = new Pool({ connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL });
  return {
    adapter: PostgresAdapter(pool),
    trustHost: true,
    ...authConfig,
  };
});


The session is null on login.
While the client-side object remains consistently valid, the issue is on server-side pages. Only occasionally, the session is populated during page navigation.
What am I missing?
I'm using "next-auth": "5.0.0-beta.20".
Tried downgrading to earlier versions, it did not help.

My issue was the code below:
export const dynamic = "force-static";
This tells next.js to render the page statically at build time.
Even if my session was valid after login, it would return it's static null value generated during the initial build.
